# How can I convert string to int? dtype("O") - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, types, pandas-groupby

I am trying to get `int` value by converting an object datatype `dtypes('O')`. What do I need to write in code to avoid the error:`invalid literal for int() with base 10:`

```
df.Weekly_Sales.head()
```

```
0     24924,5
1    46039,49
2    41595,55
3    19403,54
4     21827,9
Name: Weekly_Sales, dtype: object
```

`dataset['weeklySales'] = dataset['weeklySales'].replace(np.nan, '', regex=True).str.replace(',','')`

Now I have the following, but as `obj` type.

```
0     249245
1    4603949
2    4159555
3    1940354
4     218279
Name: Weekly_Sales, dtype: object
```

I tried,

```
df['Weekly_Sales'].astype(str).astype('int64')
```

and

```
df['Weekly_Sales'].astype(int)
```

Still getting the error:
**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**

Comment: Are you aware that the commas are likely decimal separators, and that doing this effectively renders your data meaningless?

Comment: @coldspeed yes, I am aware of it. My purpose is here to convert str to int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your dataframe to numeric using `pd.to_numeric`, fill the areas with errors with 0 (or whatever number you want), then finally cast to int:

```
df['Weekly_sales'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Weekly_sales'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
```